# Update database in android application

Tags: android

Hello I have a problem when I want update in database. Not show error but say "unfortunately app has sttoped

```
    private void guardar() {
    AdminSQLiteOpenHelper admin = new AdminSQLiteOpenHelper(this, "DietaClub", null, 1);
    SQLiteDatabase bd = admin.getWritableDatabase();
    String usuario = perfilUsuarioInput.getText().toString();
    String nombre = perfilNombreInput.getText().toString();
    String apellido = perfilApellidoInput.getText().toString();
    String sucursal = perfilSucursalInput.getText().toString();
    float peso_inicial = Float.valueOf(pesoInicial.getText().toString());
    float peso_actual = Float.valueOf(pesoActual.getText().toString());
    float peso_deseado = Float.valueOf(pesoDeseado.getText().toString());

    ContentValues registros = new ContentValues();
    registros.put("nombre", nombre);
    registros.put("apellido", apellido);
    registros.put("sucursal", sucursal);
    registros.put("peso_inicial", "asdas");
    registros.put("peso_deseado", "dasd");
    registros.put("peso_actual", "ss");
    int cant = bd.update("users", registros, "usuario="+usuario,null);
    bd.close();
    if(cant == 1){
        Intent intent = new Intent(EditarPerfilActivity.this, PerfilActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

and my database is

[image: database data]

logcat say:

```
UPDATE users SET peso_actual=?,peso_deseado=?,usuario=?...
```

Any help?

Comment: Logcat please? And see [Unfortunately MyApp has stopped. How can I solve this?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this)

Comment: I added logcat but, fileds are empty (?), why?

Comment: Did you try the answer provided below?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the example given here, I believe you are not using the SQLiteDatabase.update() function properly: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html

In your particular case, try the following:

```
bd.update("users", registros, "usuario = ?", usuario);
```

I hope that helps :)